# Adding scrollbar and then dummy text in textview make the layout beneath it vanish

Tags: android, android-layout

I added scrollbar and some dumy text in my textview which is successfully done.But by doing so the layout beneath that textview is vanished.I want that I can add as much text as I want wihtout distrubing the layouts beanth it. 
Screenshot of XML preview before adding the scrollbar :

[image]

Screenshot of after adding scrollbar and some extra dummy text :

[image]

This is my XML Code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/empty"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="3"
    tools:context=".story_activity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Story Name"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <!-- android:layout_marginLeft="140dp"-->/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:background="@drawable/story_des"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/lion" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.2"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="0.2">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/story_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:text="This specification does not indicate the behavior, rendering or otherwise, of space characters other than those explicitly identified here as white space characters. For this reason, authors should use appropriate elements and styles to achieve visual formatting effects that involve white space, rather than space characters.This specification does not indicate the behavior, rendering or otherwise, of space characters other than those explicitly identified here as white space characters. For this reason, authors should use appropriate elements and styles to achieve visual formatting effects that involve white space, rather than space characters.This specification does not indicate the behavior, rendering or otherwise, of space characters other than those explicitly identified here as white space characters. For this reason, authors should use appropriate elements and styles to achieve visual formatting effects that involve white space, rather than space characters."
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/story_rate"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Rate This Story"
                    android:textColor="#1e5aaa"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/rate"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/story_rate"
                    android:src="@drawable/star" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/rate1"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rate"
                    android:src="@drawable/star" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/rate2"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rate1"
                    android:src="@drawable/star" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/rate3"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rate2"
                    android:src="@drawable/star" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:src="@drawable/line" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/author_image"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/as" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/author_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/author_image"
                    android:fontFamily="century-gothic"
                    android:text="Author Title"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/pub_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/author_title"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/author_image"
                    android:fontFamily="century-gothic"
                    android:text="Pve sentences, cjajsxa "
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: To get you correct, you don't want the Rate this story part of the view to be pushed beneath, right?

Comment: yup.Thats what Iam asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.2"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="0.2">
```

In this part consider changing it to relative layout. Give fixed height/wrap_content to rate dialog part(linear layout with that code), then set it to match bottom. Align it to parent bottom.

As for text view set its constrains as align parent top and align bottom to start of rate dialog.

This should do the trick!